# Passing Data from View to Partial in .NET CORE

Tags: json, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20808352/2441637) and tried to implement the `ViewDataDictionary` in my app but did not work.

In my view, I've the below code:

```
@{
  var myTest = new
            {
                UserId = "cdb86aea-e3d6-4fdd-9b7f-55e12b710f78",
                UserName = "iggy",
            }; 

}
@Html.Partial("~/Partials/test.cshtml", myTest)
```

and the `test.cshtml` is very simple, when I write `@Model`, I get `{ UserId = cdb86aea-e3d6-4fdd-9b7f-55e12b710f78, UserName = iggy }`

How can I extract this as JSON, so I can read `@Model.UserName`

I tried using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@
   {
      <text>
            var obj = JSON.parse(@Model);
      </text>
   }
</script>
```

and tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      @:var obj = JSON.parse(@Model);
</script>
```

and tried:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(object))
```

but nothing worked, any help!!

Comment: Please show the HTML that gets rendered when using those code blocks.

Comment: @CodeCaster kindly see my commints to Haim answer, as I'm writting this from the mobile, difficult to copy/paste my commints again. Thankd

Comment: Can you use a type class/object instead of anonymous type? That way you won't use the intellisense.

Comment: @alltej did not get your point, can you give example, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across similar problem when I was converting my .net application into .net core.
In .net I could just ***return Json(jsonModel)*** in my controller and use it in my view as ***data.UserID***, **data.UserName** (see code below adjusted to match your sample).
In .net core I had to SerializeObject in my controller first and then use JSON.parse in the view javascript section to make it work.

The following works in .NET CORE. Assuming you have some model:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller return Json object:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[HttpPost]        
public IActionResult someAction()
{
    SomeModel jsonModel = new SomeModel();
    jsonModel.UserId = "cdb86aea-e3d6-4fdd-9b7f-55e12b710f78";
    jsonModel.UserName = "iggy";

    var serializedJsonModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonModel);
    return Json(serializedJsonModel);
 }
```

and in your view javascript section you can retrieve values from your model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.post("@Url.Action("someAction", "YourController")", 
        function (data) { 
            var oJson = JSON.parse(data);
            UserId = oJson.UserId;
            UserName = oJson.UserName; });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in JSON serialization of your anonymous type, you can simply declare the `@model` of the partial as `object`.

In your main view:

```
@{
    var myTest = new
    {
        UserId = "cdb86aea-e3d6-4fdd-9b7f-55e12b710f78",
        UserName = "iggy",
    };
}

@Html.Partial("~/Partials/test.cshtml", myTest)
```

And in your `test.cshtml` partial:

```
@model object

<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

Comment: @HasanAYousef, What exactly "doesn't work"? Is there an error?

Comment: well, my case is little different, as what I'm doing is converting the `view` into `string`, which so far works fine with me in views and partials, but once the need to read the `Model` in the `partial` as `JSON` something happened, and the page is not appearing, I'm working with this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/40950901/2441637 at the route `api/returnView`, I can email you the file if interested.

Comment: this is the full app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Zxj-0OeOEoTXVLSTdZM2xjUWc/view?usp=sharing