# Passing string from AJAX to C# code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-select2

I've looked at so many comments on this subject, and I have tried a number of suggested methods for accomplishing this but I'm still not able to access the code behind. Error message comes back with the success routine. I am using a Select2 as an input source (there is no list, only what the operator desires to enter) for multiple entries to be passed via ajax to my code behind. I believe the data type may not be the same as the code behind but not sure how to define it other than what I have, or has it been depracated and I am not aware. I changed to the original programming when the error occurred. myData is changed to model to match code behind.
Here is what I get in the select2 if I put in "test" and "copy".

> After model value is: test,copy

Here is my Client side code:

```
...
<select id="SearchSelect" style="width: 150px" name="SearchSelct" 
multiple onmouseover="SearchTip('#SrchToolTip','#hdnviewsrch');return 
false;"></select>
    <textarea id="SrchToolTip" style="color:blue" hidden="hidden">You can 
enter any keyword you like.</textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
<asp:Button ID="SearchFnd" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
OnClientClick="SearchSel('#SearchSelect');return false;" 
ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //On client side - Here we render the Select 2
    $("#SearchSelect").select2(
    {
        placeholder: "Enter Search Parameters",
        tags: true,  
        tokenSeparators: [','], 
        allowClear: true,  
        minimumInputLength: 1,  
        width: 'resolve',   
        });
    });
    $("#SearchSelect").on("change", function (e) { 
SearchChange("SearchSelect"); });

    function SearchTip(SrchElem) {
        $(SrchElem).show();
        console.log("Search Tip value is: " + $("#SearchSelect").val());
        };

    function SearchChange(name, evt) {
        console.log("Search Change value is: " + $("#SearchSelect").val() 
+ "; Name: " + name);
    };
    function SearchSel(SchElem) {
        var model= { "SrchData": $(SchElem).val() };
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",    
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/SearchFind") %>', 
            data: JSON.stringify(model.SrchData),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
                console.log("Search data obtained: " + result);
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error: " + errorThrown);
            },
            failure: function () {
            alert('Failure');
            }
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                console.log("Search data obtained: " + data);
                return {
                    results: data.d,
                    pagination: {
                        more: data.more
                    }

                };
             }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace WebApplication2
{
  public partial class _Default : Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public class Schdata
    {
        public string SrchData { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod()]
    //  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string SearchFind(Schdata model)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Went into the SearchFind 
        subroutine " + model.SrchData);
        return "1";
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

> success! {"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

The program says it is successful but gives an error that the value is null being returned (or sent) but on the code behind I have a breakpoint at the System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine... line and it never reaches there. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried visiting <%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/SearchFind") %> to ensure its reachable by the client? Failing that can you ensure that the expected data is being posted?

Comment: This is functionable. I have used this in many other pages. The only way I know is to write it to the console before I send through Ajax. Also, I have stringified teh answer before I went in to Ajax but it did not change anything. Thanks.

Comment: See if my answer in the link below would help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957556/passing-data-from-view-to-partial-in-net-core/44831001#44831001

Comment: doesn't this need to be "model" instead of "SrchData" to match parameter of webmethod. var myData = { "SrchData": $(SchElem).val() };

Comment: The two links are identical. I mainly want to pass the values to my code behind. I'm only retrieving data to show I completed the process. Can you tell me what the goal would be to use HTTP Post instead of Ajax? I'm using Ajax in every other instance on my pages. Is HTTP better? I've altered my code to stringify the return value but no change. Thanks for your input

Comment: SrchDadta is an element of model.

Comment: sorry, SrchData

Comment: I've tried so many combinations of data types and methods, here is what I started out with:    data: JSON.stringify(model.SrchData),

Comment: model is a type of SchData in the code behind, so var model = "SrchData": $(SchElem).val() }; is what I used originally.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
   string myStrCb = "Value from back";
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     //... any code
   }
   // ...more code
}
```

In your front code

```
<script>
  var myJsVar = <%=myStrCb %>
</script>
```

Use in script

```
function WriteValue()
{
  console.log(myJsVar); // Value from back
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time but this is not my problem. I can get any data I want from back end, it's getting values from Ajax to the Back end that is the problem. I am receiving a success from AJAX but it is not going to the subroutine in server side and giving me an error message of null value.